# Conditional rendering with React Router

Tags: react-router

I'd like to render some routes with a nav at the top, while rendering other routes (like a sign-up / sign-in page) without any nav.

[image: render example with react router]

For the setup with the nav, I have:

```
const App = () => (
  <Router>
    <div>
      <Nav />
      <div>
        <Route exact path="/" component={Home} />
        <Route path="/account" component={Account} />
        <Route path="/news" component={News} />
      </div>
      <Footer />
    </div>
  </Router>
);
```

I'm trying to find the best way of handling this with React Router (seems like it would have to handled with some type of conditional maybe? - "if my current route matches any one of these routes, then render like so else render this.").

Thanks!

Comment: This seems to answer your question https://stackoverflow.com/questions/53780075/excluding-header-component-on-a-specific-page-with-react-router/53785226

Answer (score 9):

You have at least two possibilities:

1. Use `Route` "path" property to test the route and render the component. Path property accepts [`path.to.regexp`](https://reacttraining.com/react-router/web/api/Route/path-string) expressions.
2. Wrap your component with [`withRouter`](https://reacttraining.com/react-router/web/api/withRouter) method and inside `Nav` test if the route matches and render `null` otherwise.

First answer:

```
const App = () => (
  <Router>
    <div>
      <Route path="/(?!signin|signup)" component={Nav}/>
      <div>
        <Route exact path="/" component={Home} />
        <Route path="/account" component={Account} />
        <Route path="/news" component={News} />
      </div>
      <Footer />
    </div>
  </Router>
);
```

Second answer:

```
import { withRouter } from 'react-router'
const NavWithRouter = withRouter(Nav);

const App = () => (
  <Router>
    <div>
      <NavWithRouter/>
      <div>
        <Route exact path="/" component={Home} />
        <Route path="/account" component={Account} />
        <Route path="/news" component={News} />
      </div>
      <Footer />
    </div>
  </Router>
);
```

Answer (score 1):

`` <Route
    path={`foo/(A|B|C)`} 
    component={() => (<Baz {...props}/>)}
/> ``

Where `A,B,C` are the different routes like `foo/A`.

Answer (score 1):

I usually use two different Layout pages. And within the Layout pages, have a router for the content.

My code will look like this:

```
<Router>
  <Route path="/login" component={AuthLayout} />
  <Route path="/logout" component={AuthLayout} />
  <Route path="/some/path" component={Layout} />
</Router>
```

Within each Layout, there will be the usual header / footer / navbars and then another set of routes.

```
<div className="auth-layout">
  <header className="auth-layout__header"></header>
  <main className="auth-layout__content">
    <Switch>
      <Route path="/login" component={Login} />
      <Route path="/logout" component={Logout} />
    </Switch>
  </main>
</div>
```

In this way, I have a direct mapping from requirements to code. In my code, there are much more differences between the two layouts.

Answer (score -2):

Just use a prop for this & inside the children your are able to conditional render the nav.

`<Route exact path="/" render={() => <Home hasNav={false} />}`