# Excluding <Header /> component on a specific page with react-router

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-router

Here's a working code:

```
const AppRouter = () => (
<BrowserRouter>
  <div>
    <Header />
    <Switch>
      <Route path="/" component={DashboardPage} exact={true} />
      <Route path="/:id" component={ViewerPage} /> // <-- Exclude Header component from this page
      <Route path="/create" component={CreatePage} />
      <Route path="/edit/:id" component={EditPage} />
      <Route path="/help" component={HelpPage} />
      <Route component={NotFoundPage} />
    </Switch>
  </div>
</BrowserRouter>
);

export default AppRouter;
```

I couldn't seem to figure out how to exclude the Header component from ViewerPage component page. Is there any way to do this?

Comment: Wrap `<Header />` component with some condition...

Comment: @Rayon, how would that look like?

Comment: Something like `URL === SOMETHING ? null : <Header />`

Comment: Under what condition should the component appear/not appear?

Comment: Exclude it on only one specific route? `{location.pathname !== '/route-to-exclude-header' && <Header />}` If you want to exclude on more than one route make an array of exclusion paths and then `{exclusionArray.indexOf(location.pathname) > 0 && <Header/>}` Use the `withRouter` HoC provided by `react-router` package to inject `location` into your component.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

The [withRouter](https://reacttraining.com/react-router/web/api/withRouter) Higher-order-Component provided by the `react-router` package will give you access to the location object. Once you have that you can conditionally render the header by short-circuiting.

```
import {withRouter} from 'react-router'

const App = ({location}) => (
  <div>
    {location.pathname !== '/exclusion-path' && <Header/>}
    <Switch>
      ...
    </Switch>
  </div>
)

export default withRouter(App)
```

or to exclude on multiple paths...

```
const exclusionArray = [
  '/path-one',
  '/another-path',
]

const App = ({location}) => (
  <div>
    {exclusionArray.indexOf(location.pathname) < 0 && <Header/>}
    <Switch>
      ...
    </Switch>
  </div>
)
```

If you're doing anything serious I'd recommend using the context api and short-circuit on a value provided by context. If this is the case and you need some direction I'd be happy to explain it to you.

P.S. If you want to do it with the alpha Hooks API I'll get really excited.

EDIT: To address commont.

Move your Router outside of the App component.

```
import {BrowserRouter as Router} from 'react-router-dom'
import ReactDOM from 'react-dom'

ReactDOM.render(
  <Router>
    <App/>
  </Router>,
  document.getElementById('render-target')
)
```

Comment: Here's what I'm getting... `Uncaught Error: You should not use <Route> or withRouter() outside a <Router>`

Comment: Move your `<Router/>` outside of the App component. Refer to edit.

Comment: I'm trying to use the context API by having a HeaderConsumer/HeaderProvider with an updateHeader function for adding elements to the header, but I think I'm usingthe API wrong. Any suggestions @KyleRichardson?

Answer (score 22):

Had the exact same requirement in my last project and I went with the approach of splitting the header out into its own component and the using React Fragments. Idiomatic!

```
import React, { Fragment } from 'react'
// ...

const App = () => (
  <div>
    <Switch>
      <Route path='/no-header-route' component={NoHeaderComponent} />   // Route without header
      <Fragment>            // This is the key
        <Header/>           // Header is in its own component
        <Route path='/route-1' component={Comp1}/>  // Route with header
        <Route path='/route-2' component={Comp2}/>  // Route with header
      </Fragment>
    </Switch>
  </div>
)
```

Comment: By far the most elegant solution here! Exactly what I was looking for, well done!

Comment: Exactly the most elegant answer for the struggling problem. Your answer saved my whole day. Thanks

Comment: Your way is keep rendering 404page in every component. Is there anyway to prevent this?

Comment: If anybody reading this comment I want to add one more point here, in my case it was not working if I add  <Route path='/no-header-route' component={NoHeaderComponent} /> below  closing  </Fragment>

Answer (score 0):

1- something like, In Header.js

```
  import {withRouter} from 'react-router-dom';

        class Header extends Component {
          render() {
            if (this.props.location.pathname === '/') {
              return null
            }
            return (
              // other stuff
            );
          }
        }
  export default withRouter(Header);
```

Note that, withRouter can be different with different react router version. But idea is the same: check your pathname with ViewerPage's pathname, and do not display Header if it is the path...

2- Other approach is do the same thing with 'redux'

so whenever ViewerPage is loaded, dispatch an action.
In ViewerPage.js

```
class ViewerPage extends Component {
          componentDidMount() {
            this.props.updateShouldDisplayHeader(false);
          }
          componentWillUnmount(){
             this.props.updateShouldDisplayHeader(true);
           }
        }
```

In Header.js

```
class Header extends Component {
          render() {
            if(!this.props.shouldDisplayHeader) {
               return null;
            }
            return (
              // other stuff
            );
          }
        }
```

I suppose you already know how to create action and use reducers on redux

Comment: He wants to conditionally render the header. You can short-circuit this in the containing component that would render the header.

Answer (score 0):

In your Router file call [useRouteMatch()](https://reactrouter.com/web/api/Hooks/useroutematch) before a `<Switch>`

```
export Routes = (
{useRouteMatch("/specific-route")?.isExact ? (
          <Header />
        ) : null}

<Switch>
  <Route path="other/path" component={Other}
  ...
</Switch>
);
```

Alternatively, call [withRouter()](https://reactrouter.com/web/api/withRouter) to have direct access to `match`, `location` and `history`.

```
export const AuthenticatedRoutes = withRouter(() => (
  {location.pathname !== `/special-url` ? (
    <Header />
  ) : null}

  <Route path="/special-url" component={Special}
  <Route path="/other" component={Other} 
));

export Routes = (
  {useRouteMatch("/specific-route")?.isExact ? (
    <Header />
  ) : null}
            
  <Switch>
    <Route component={AuthenticatedRoutes}          
  </Switch>
);
```