# Hide Sidenav and navbar for some routes in react opening in new window

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-router-dom

How to hide this sidenav and top navbar for certain route path that will launch in new window?

So https://{ipAddress}/dashboard is mapped to a component that renders this sideNav, navbar, and content area...
so if i select any task from sidebar say View User then https://{ipAddress}/dashboard/viewUser
then viewuser component will be rendered in that content area.

Now i have a requirement where i need to launch say https://{ipAddress}/dashboard/update...
in new window.. but it should not show sidenav n top navbar.

We are using router v6.

[Conditional rendering with React Router](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46842117/conditional-rendering-with-react-router)
this works if route is being rendered in same tab..but if you opening in new window altogether..it does not work

[image]

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Conditional rendering with React Router](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46842117/conditional-rendering-with-react-router)

Comment: @scriptydude no it works if its same tab..not for new window